# How to find out that upload is complete in Webix FileManager

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webix

I am using FileManager from Webix in a Rails application. Most of it is ok, but  when I Upload a large file, the progress bar moves until the end, regardless of the size and regardless it has already uploaded the file to the server. The user then leaves the screen and the transfer is cancelled and the file is not uploaded.

How do I know that the upload is finished and ok? There is a onBeforeUpload event but not a onAfterUpload event, How do I prevent the user from leaving the screen until the upload is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle two events

- onFileUpload
- onFileUploadError

First one for a upload success handler, second for a upload error handler.

http://docs.webix.com/api__ui.uploader_onfileupload_event.html

Also, if code allows to upload multiple files at once, it will be better to handle onUploadComplete event, instead of the onFileUpload

http://docs.webix.com/api__ui.uploader_onuploadcomplete_event.html

All above is events of uploader widget, you can access them like

```
files.getUploader().attachEvent("onUploadComplete", function(){
  /*...*/
});
```

> How do I prevent the user from leaving the screen

There is no native solution, you can use common js way to handle such situation - define onunload handler for the whole page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I used the events you mentioned plus the 'onAfterFileAdd'. I show a modal when the upload starts and hide it when it finishes. Thank You Very Much! Obs: the Filemanager control has the id 'files' and created a modal div with id 'uploadModal'.
`
$$('files').getUploader().attachEvent 'onAfterFileAdd', () ->
      $('#uploadModal').modal('show');
      
    $$('files').getUploader().attachEvent 'onFileUpload', (item,response) ->
      $('#uploadModal').modal('hide');
`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code with the correct events: 
filemanager.js.coffee

```
class FileManager
  constructor: (@element) ->
  @token = @element.data('token')
  @type = @element.data('type')
  @usermail = @element.data('usermail')
  webix.ready(@render)

  fmResize: () ->
    t = 40
    h = $(window).height() - t
    w = $(window).width()
    $$("files").define( width: w, height: h )
    $$("files").resize()

  options: () ->
    view: 'filemanager'
    left: 100
    id: 'files'
    container: @element.attr('id')
    handlers:
      branch: @actionUrl('load_folder')
      search: @actionUrl('search')
      upload: @actionUrl('upload')
      download: @actionUrl('download')
      copy: @actionUrl('copy')
      move: @actionUrl('move')
      remove: @actionUrl('remove')
      rename: @actionUrl('rename')
      create: @actionUrl('create')
    url: '/file_manager/load_root_folders'
      return

  actionUrl: (action) ->
    "/file_manager/" + action + "?authenticity_token=" +     encodeURIComponent(@token)

  render: () =>
    webix.i18n.setLocale('pt-BR');
    new webix.ui(@options())

    $$('files').attachEvent 'onErrorResponse', (requestData,response) ->
      action = requestData.action
      webix.message(response)
      return false

    $$('files').getUploader().attachEvent 'onAfterFileAdd', () ->
      $('#uploadModal').modal('show');

    $$('files').getUploader().attachEvent 'onFileUpload', (item,response) ->
      $('#uploadModal').modal('hide');

    $$('files').getUploader().attachEvent 'onFileUploadError', (item,response) ->
      $('#uploadModal').modal('hide');
      webix.alert({
        title: "Carga de Arquivos",
        text: "Erro na carga do arquivo!",
        type: "alert-error"
        });

    $$('files').getUploader().attachEvent 'onUploadComplete', (item,response) ->
      $('#uploadModal').modal('hide');

$(document).ready () ->
  if $('#fileCanvas').length > 0
    fm = new FileManager($('#fileCanvas'))
    $(window).resize ->
      fm.fmResize()
```

Html:

```
<div id="fileCanvas" data-usermail="<%= current_user.email %>" data-token="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" data-type="<%= current_user.member_of_admins? ? :admin : :user %>"></div>
<div id="uploadModal" class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Carga de Arquivos</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Agurade o término da carga do arquivo. não feche ou saia dessa janela</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```